# Adding a date for the Maximum of three dates in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Could you please help me on fetching the date +1 for the maximum of three dates?
Description:

I have built a code in XSLT to fetch maximum of three dates.I want to add one date for the maximum date what i get .

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks & Regards,
Gowthami H J

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here we help you with YOUR code, rather than do work for you. Please show us what you've tried, and explain any problem you're facing. Then we can help.

Comment: @Utkanos the website in yout profile seems to be not working (and it's "Utkonos" with o:)

Comment: <xsl:variable name="StaffingEventDate" select="/pi:Employee/pi:Status/pi:Staffing_Event_Date"/>
 <xsl:variable name="CurrDatePlusOne" select="xs:string($StaffingEventDate) ,xs:string('P1D')" />

Comment: Here is the piece of code which i tried for one date instaed of maximum of 3 dates.If i get an idea or this i can work for maximum of three dates
<xsl:variable name="StaffingEventDate" select="/pi:Employee/pi:Status/pi:Staffing_Event_Date"/>
 <xsl:variable name="CurrDatePlusOne" select="xs:string($StaffingEventDate) ,xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')" />

<xsl:value-of select="date.add($StaffingEventDate, 'P1D')"/>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use XSLT 2 or 3 (which the use of `xs:string` suggests) you can simply apply the date arithmetic https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dateTime-arithmetic provided in XPath 2 and later for the `xs:date/xs:dateTime` and the duration data types e.g. in

```
max(item/xs:date(.)) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
```

`max(item/xs:date(.))` computes the maximum date of the sequence of `item` elements and the `+` operator adds a duration of one day.

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTX